# How do I prevent a redirect loop when forwarding from http to https using rails and elastic beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx

I just installed an ssl certificate in my Rails app and I am now trying to redirect all http traffic to https. It is hosted on AWS elastic beanstalk. I have followed the directions to adjust the nginx config to serve ssl. The problem is that it still allows http traffic. Every solution I have found has either plain failed or resulted in a redirect loop. (adding a new server block to the config for port 80 to handle the redirect; adding if directives to redirect when the protocol type is http; etc.)

below is my additional nginx configuration file from `.ebextensions`:

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf:
    content: |
      # HTTPS server

      server {
          listen       443;
          server_name  localhost;

          ssl                  on;
          ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

          ssl_session_timeout  5m;

          ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
          ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

          location / {
              proxy_pass  http://my_app.com;
              proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
          }

          location /assets {
            alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
            gzip_static on;
            gzip on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
          }

          location /public {
            alias /var/app/current/public;
            gzip_static on;
            gzip on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
          }
      }

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      REDACTED CERTIFICATE HERE
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      -----END CERTIFICATE----- 

container_commands:
  01restart_nginx:
    command: "service nginx restart"
```

This configuration works, but I need a redirect strategy. I suspect that it is the fact that the configuration proxies to http://my_app.com that causes the loop, but I don't know where else to send it for Rails to pick up the request. What am I doing wrong? How do I redirect all http traffic to https without creating a loop? I absolutely do not want to involve a load balancer by the way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I will go for application LB instead of nginx. ALB will redirect to https without exposing port at instance level.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was simpler than I thought. I'm still not sure how to prevent that redirect loop, but I can use the Rails setting:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

to accomplish what I want to do and route all http traffic to use https.